# Parse test push notification with development certificate

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I  have live application that uses Parse notification feature. I would like to test some methods especially this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification
```

But the problem is that we have production certificate configured and added on Parse, but I debug my app with development one. Can I added development certificate and keep production as well. I needed for test messages that I receive.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is an option where we can download up to 6 certificates. I just uploaded Apple Development iOS Push Services certificate that I exported with a key as p12.

Just go to the settings then push and simple add new one certificate to enable it to test and debug on device.